# How to draw nodes in D3 Javascript library based on JSON file

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am trying to draw nodes (circles) in D3 Javascript library based on the following JSON file:

```
{
 "nodes":[{"name":["Node1", "Node2", "Node3"]}, 
          {"name":["Node4"]},
          {"name":["Node5"]}]
}
```

Here are my codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Sample2</title>
<style>

.node {
stroke: #fff;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>
var width = 960,
height = 500;
var color = d3.scale.category20();
var force = d3.layout.force()
.charge(-120)
.linkDistance(30)
.size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height);

d3.json("folder/jsonsample.json", function(error, graph) {
force
.nodes(graph.nodes) 
.start();

 var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("r", 10)
    .call(force.drag);

node.append("title")
    .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

force.on("tick", function() {
node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
});
});
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

With this HTML file, I drew only three circles because the code is based on the fact that there are three names. I would like to draw five nodes (circles) since I have `Node1, Node2, Node3, Node4 and Node5` inside the `"name, name, and name"`. Could anyone please help me draw five circles. Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I doubt this. I had tested it with more than one node. It shows two circles in this case. What I want in this case is to get 6 circles drawn as I have two nodes and in each nodes there are three names. Any idea, please?

Comment: With this code and json file I got 3 black circles. I am not sure if I understand the problem.

Comment: Did you change anything with the code? When I run that file, I get only one circle.

Comment: No, cut&paste of everything to two files. For each additional {"name":"NodeXY"} I get another circle as expected.

Comment: You are right. I am sorry about that. I have updated the question for your consideration.

Comment: Any reason not to have 5 elements in your array?

Comment: Well. I am having a big amount of data on JSON file. It looks similar to this JSON format. I tried to store them in an array but I am afraid I am missing something in the codes. Any idea how to manage this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use **Collapsible Force Layout**, see example at [mbostock block](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288). With that example and the following json file (changed his readme.json file):

```
{
 "name": "example",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "group1",
   "children": [
      {"name": "node1", "size": 3000},
      {"name": "node2", "size": 3000},
      {"name": "node3", "size": 3000}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "node4", "size": 5000
  },
  {
    "name": "node5", "size": 10000
  }
 ]
}
```

you can get something similar. You get one root element with 3 children, one has 3 nodes. See [image]

If you select root node everything colapse.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. At some point, this is what I need. I would like to understand the codes. Is there any tutorial that I ca go through and understand how that was implemented?

Comment: Check out [tutorials](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials), [mbostock’s blocks](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock) and [Mike Bostock page](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/). Additionally, there are two books: Scott Murray, _Interactive Data Visualization for the Web_ and Mike Dewar, _Getting Started with D3_. Besides JS and D3.js, some basics of SVG are helpful.